# Can I create a Linux distribution based on elementary OS?

Tags: elementary-project

Good afternoon,
I am a developer and i would like to know if I have the right to creat a distribution base on elementary OS.

cordially, rivens

Ps: sorry for my bad English it's because i'm french

Answer (score 1):

I'm not on the elementary development team or anything but there is this.

--> https://elementary.io/get-involved

At that link they state "Everything that we make is 100% open source and developed collaboratively by people from all over the world. Even if you're not a programmer, you can get involved and make a difference."

I think it's safe to say that you're only bound by the terms of the GNU-GPL which should be easy as long as the distro that you want to create would also be open source.  More reading on the GNU-GPL can be found at https://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license

Also you can verify this for yourself by going through all the project listings on the [elementaryos github account page](https://github.com/elementary?page=1) and looking at the license, see the attached picture for details.

[image]

If you see a license that you don't know off hand you can look it up [here](https://opensource.org/search/node/mit) by typing it as it appears on github.

Hope that helps :)